# VBA collections - Read values into collection from static range

Tags: excel, vba, collections, runtime

I'm trying to get a range of values into a new collection. Range is fixed, empty cells are supposed to be skipped, cells with content added to the collection. However, I get an error saying

> "Object variable or With block variable not set"

on the line

```
"ISINsLX0358 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Splits_Vormonat").Range("B3:BK3")"
```

Can somebody tell me why this is happening and help me improve my code?

```
Dim collLX0358 As New Collection
Dim ISINsLX0358 As Range

Set collLX0358 = Nothing

ISINsLX0358 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Splits_Vormonat").Range("B3:BK3")

For Each isin In ISINsLX0358
    If isin <> "" Then
        coll.Add isin
    End If
Next isin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voila:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    'Dim collLX0358  As New Collection - you are not using it, -> you do not need it.
    Dim ISINsLX0358 As Range

    Dim isin        As Range
    Dim coll        As New Collection
    'Set collLX0358 = Nothing - WHY?

    Set ISINsLX0358 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B3:BK3")

    For Each isin In ISINsLX0358
        If isin <> "" Then
            coll.Add isin
        End If
    Next isin

End Sub
```

---

- Start using `Option Explicit`
- What is the idea of `Set colLX0358 = Nothing`. As far as you are not using it, remove it from the code.
- `Range` is an object in VBA and it should be used with the word `Set`